# I want to extract text from Ms word file in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in Asp.net mvc and this is my first web based application in which i will extract text from word file and extract grammatical mistakes. but don't know how i can extract text from word file?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+read+text+word+file

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET a good way to work with Word documents is the Open XML SDK, because it doesnt need a word installation on the server.

You habe to install the Open XML SDK and add a references to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll and WindowsBase.dll to your project.
Then you can open your document and read/replace text like this:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

class WordTest
{
    public static void ReplaceTextInWordDoc()
    {
        string filepath = "C:\\Tmp\\MyWordDoc.docx";
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
        {
            Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            foreach (var paragraph in body.Elements<Paragraph>())
            {
                foreach (var run in paragraph.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        if (text.Text.Contains("old"))
                            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("old", "new");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please write full fledged action method and view because i have tried so many time but it does not work

Comment: OK, I combined the code snippets to one executable method.

Comment: What post do vou mean? You find the executable method in the answer above. Just copy it to your programming environment.

Comment: Listen i am new in ASP.NET ? i do not understand how this should be placed in action method? would you please write view and action method?

Comment: The method is ordinary business logic and can be called from whereever you want. Sorry, I don't have the time to write a complete project here. If you don't know how to call a method, maybe you should read a basic book first.